# Are there standards such as ISO or from FDA for Ambu-bag (bag valve mask) size, dimenstions and design?

Tags: covid-19, mechanical-ventilation

Are there standards such as ISO or from FDA for Ambu-bag (bag valve mask) size, dimenstions and design?
We are designing an ambu-bag based ventilator, however, if the ambu-bags purchased at different locations are different we will need to consider that as well.

Comment: does this help http://ambu.com.br/Admin/Public/DWSDownload.aspx?File=%2FFiles%2FFiler%2FAustralia%2FDatasheets%2FAnaesthesia%2FResuscitators%2FAUS_SPUR_II_493200097_V02_0712.pdf ?

Comment: No, I'm looking if there are any standards with respect to design of the ambu bag.

Answer (score 1):

The following standard, EN [ISO 10651-4:2002](https://www.iso.org/obp/ui#iso:std:iso:10651:-4:ed-1:v1:en)
Lung ventilators Part 4: Particular requirements for operator-powered resuscitators

is for AMBU Bags!

Comment: Can you provide a link to that standard?